# Deployed the app at heroku in node js its showing Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)

Tags: node.js, heroku, next.js

I have projects in next js and node js. The version of node js is "node": "14.17.5" and next js version is  12.0.4 and I deployed that project at heroku its showing the error:- Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
For that, I also changed this code:-

```
  "scripts": {
   "build:server": "tsc -p server/tsconfig.json",
    "build:next": "next build",
    "build": "npm run build:next && npm run build:server",
    "start": "node --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=460 server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
},
```

If anyone have any more idea please suggest me. Thank you in advance.